# How can we leave the fullscreen mode in Haskell OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, haskell, fullscreen

In HOpenGL, I can enter fullscreen mode with the function fullScreen:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.1.1.2/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Window.html#v%3AfullScreen

But, how can we leave the fullscreen mode? Is there a function to leave the fullscreen mode? I used the function fullScreenToogle but I get a runtime error:

user error (unknown GLUT call glutFullScreenToggle, check for freeglut)

Comment: Do you have some example/test code?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `fullScreen` again?

Comment: Yes, I tried calling the function fullScreen again without success.

Comment: Are you using 2.1?  The documentation for 2.5 looks better.

Comment: OpenGL
    Synopsis: A binding for the OpenGL graphics system
    Default available version: 2.9.0.0
    Installed versions: 2.2.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You will need to call `setWindowSize :: Size -> IO ()` to exit full screen. This function internally calls `glutReshapeWindow` which leads to exit from full screen. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13084584/553209) answer.

Comment: Not in scope: `setWindowSize'

I tried windowSize $= Size 640 480 without success:

 case key of
  ...
  Char 'F' ->
   fullScreen
  Char 'W' ->
   windowSize $= Size 640 480
  _ -> return ()

Answer (score 0):

My answer to Ankur:

Not in scope: `setWindowSize'

I tried windowSize $= Size 640 480 without success:

```
case key of
 ...
 Char 'F' ->
  fullScreen
 Char 'W' ->
  windowSize $= Size 640 480
 _ -> return ()
```

I added this piece of code to this example:

KeyboardAndMouse3DAnimation.hs

http://pastebin.com/W14KSeLj