# Compile time string assignment for run-time identification

Tags: c++, inheritance, cstring, stdstring, compile-time

I've been using a pattern in a library I'm creating that uses passes a String name of an object to its base object's constructor. I've tried using std::string and c-style strings but keep getting weird memory errors with Valgrind.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base( std::string name ) : name(name) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    std::string getName() { return name; }
private:
    std::string name;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base("Derived") {}
};

int main() {
    Base* derived = new Derived;
    std::cout << derived->getName() << "\n";
    delete derived;
}
```

(This compiles and runs fine in Valgrind)

Is something like this safe? I'm using 'const char*' instead of 'std::string' right now, is that safe?

Is there a safer alternative, preferably without using virtuals?

Edit: Is there a way to do this with templates? I don't want to use RTTI since it has the name mangled and I want the name to be 'normal' for use with scripting/data persistance.

Comment: Your base class needs to have a virtual destructor (this is probably the cause of the errors you're seeing). Also, you should probably use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Just checked, all the bases are virtual in my code.

Comment: For string literal constants, do not use a smart pointer a la `std::unique_ptr< char const[] >( "hello" )` because the `char const *` points to static data storage, not the heap. And I don't see the question here, this code is safe and fine but apparently doesn't represent the problematic part.

Comment: Alright thanks, thats what I was asking. I've read posts about problems with static initialization of strings, and had bizarre errors when I switched CStrings to std::strings. Just wanted to make sure this was safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you do here is fine.

Templates would get you nothing because you still need to store a runtime pointer in the base class for dynamic identification.

Smart pointers would get you nothing because the lifetime of the string is the entire program. If you aren't computing anything, `char const *` and initialization from a string literal are ideal. If you are computing the string, then you can use `static std::string const` wrapped in a getter function.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base(get_name()) {}
private:
    static std::string const & get_name() {
        static std::string const name = "Derived"; // or = compute_name();
        return name;
    }
};
```

This avoids the static initialization order fiasco. (The getter function receives an extra multithreading-safe guard from the compiler.) The lifetime of the `string` is the lifetime of the program. The `Base` may store a `string const &` or a `char const *`, it doesn't really matter. I would recommend `char const *` because the `string` reference could potentially be accidentally initialized with a temporary.

Comment: Buyer beware: Visual C++ does not implement thread-safe initialization of function-local statics.

Comment: @Casey Are you sure? It's not a complicated feature.

Comment: Very sure. [Here's a question about VS2010.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585928/is-static-init-thread-safe-with-vc2010) I've personally researched VS2012. Apparently it's [planned for "post-2013 release"](https://udta1g.blu.livefilestore.com/y2pMXBJL7l2a5UOf_pXnLXghSUhPWK8w5skFyc50SVFcMjVwa1guQnM6R0NNLN1buBUNPGbLBejpYXXBXSbqshQKKWVfQxvJjk2jGRPPbL-UBu7gaao4RxifZgPXY5ksdei/image1.png?psid=1).

Comment: @Casey I'll be darned, there it is. That compiler must be very crufty inside if inserting some boilerplate around every `static` local initialization represents real programming effort.